# Why aren't people pouring ethanol my unskinned chicken to remove excessive fat?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents, food-chemistry

I see a lot of people putting cooked chicken thighs on paper towels to absorb the excessive fat. This gave me an idea: if you don't care about taste, why can't we rinse cooked chicken with ethanol and pour away the mixture?

The ethanol will quickly evaporate and the *excessive* grease from the chicken will be rinsed away.

Comment: Sounds like this might work, but it is way more expensive than the conventional method.

Comment: I can't help but consider the possibility of fried chicken which can get you drunk. Now there's something with the potential to take off...

Comment: And, perhaps some of us do care about the taste? Heck, we could soak them in carbon tetrachloride - that would degrease them nice and quick...

Comment: Poulet Flambé, anyone?

Comment: @JonCuster Too toxic

Comment: @Sparrowcide - yes, I'm quite familiar with the health issues with carbon tet - that was tongue-in-cheek. But I'm not about to start pouring grain alcohol over my chicken either - the remaining fat comes off in a paper towel just fine, which then gets thrown away. Your solution causes additional disposal problems with no net gain.